# C# class property that represents a const string

Tags: c#, asp.net

Consider this code:

```
public static class PredefinedStrings
{
    public const string Golf = "Golfing";
    public const string Basketball = "Basketball";
    public const string HoolaHoops = "Hulahoops";
}
```

```
public class Sports 
{ 
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How can I force the Name property of the Sports class to use only one of the PredifinedStrings?

**Edit:**  I want to avoid using enums since the values always represent a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using an `enum` instead:

```
public enum SportName { Golfing, Basketball };

public class Sports 
{ 
   public SportName Name { get; set; }
}
```

A typical assignment then would be

```
var s = new Sports();
s.Name = SportName.Basketball;
```

Even then it is not enforced since you still could do `Name = (SportName)42;` but it is much harder to get wrong - but you could certainly put custom logic into the setter to filter out these invalid values.

Also if you need the *string representation* of your enum value just use `ToString()` on it.

Comment: I should've specified, I would like to avoid using enums since I'm looking for string representations, not integer values.

Comment: This the implementation syntax, I want though, I just want to know if I can do this somehow with const strings.  I've played around with using Description attributes on enums, but this feels fundamentally incorrect since the value is just a static string.

Comment: @Victor: Then you would have to go with a run time check to make sure the value is with in a set of strings and throw an exception otherwise

Comment: there's no way to do this with inheritance?  the problem with the enum example you have is that I need the string value of the enum, not the enum type as the property of the class.

Comment: you could just return `SportName.Basketball.ToString()` or in the property case `Name.ToString()`

Comment: And I guess if I need strings with spaces I would have to revert to using data annotations and Description attributes?  So basically there's no way to do what I am wanting in my above example.  bummer.

Comment: You could do this with inheritance basically have the property of type `ILimitedString` to be used as a marker interface, then have concrete classes which each provide a particular string value - but this would be a maintenance problem in my opinion as it's not straightforward at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
public class Sports 
{ 
   private string _name;
   public string Name
   {
       get { return _name; }
       set { if (value == PredefinedStrings.Golf
                 || value == PredefinedStrings.Basketball
                 || value == PredefinedStrings.Hulahoops)
              {
                  _name = value;
              }
              else
              {
                  throw new ArgumentException ("Invalid value");
              }
            }
   }
}
```

That's the simple, naive solution. Some tweaks include creating your own class (`SportName`, for instance) and use that instead of `string`, and wrap this logic in the class. Also, instead of manually listing all the constants in the if() clause, you can have an array of strings and check if the `value` is contained in it.

Lots of other ways. :)

Answer (score -1):

or you could create an Instance of the Sports class and since the other class is Static access it's members by using it's fully qualified Class name

```
Sports newSport = new Sports();
newSport.Name = PredefinedStrings.Basketball;
```

personally I would recommend using an enum but since you asked about how to access the constants in the Static Class I posted a quick and dirty way as an example :)